# s3cmd: searching for files based on extension and delete from bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, s3cmd

I have a S3 bucket with thousands of folders and many txt files inside those folders.

I would like to list all txt files inside the bucket so I can check if they're removable. Then remove them if they are.

Any idea how to do this with s3cmd?

Answer (score 10):

This is fairly simple, but depends on how sophisticated you want the check to be. Suppose you wanted to remove every text file whose filename includes 'foo':

```
s3cmd --recursive ls s3://mybucket |
    awk '{ print $4 }' | grep "*.txt" | grep "foo" | xargs s3cmd del
```

If you want a more sophisticated check than grep can handle, just redirect the first three commands to a file, then either manually edit the file or use or `awk` or `perl` or whatever your favorite tool is, then `cat` the output into `s3cmd` (depending on the check, you could do it all with piping, too):

```
s3cmd --recursive ls s3://mybucket | awk '{ print $4 }' | grep "*.txt" > /tmp/textfiles
magic-command-to-check-filenames /tmp/textfiles
cat /tmp/textfiles | xargs s3cmd del
```